# What is wrong with this jQuery .blur?

Tags: jquery, debugging, blur

I have this jQuery:

```
var testTitleVal = $('#testTitle').val();
$('#testTitle').blur( 
       function(){
           if(testTitleVal.length == 0){
                 $('#testTitle').val('Title');
           }
       });
```

to work on this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="testTitle">
```

What I want it to accomplish is that when the focus leaves that `input` and there is no text in the input it makes the value be `Title`. For some reason it is not doing that. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `testTitleVal`? As far as I can tell, there is not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you code is a bit off in the if statement:

do this instead:

```
$('#testTitle').blur( 
   function(){
       if($(this).val().length == 0){
             $(this).val('Title');
       }
   });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/C6aau/

Comment: thats weird, it works now, but I did have the variable defined above it: `var testTitleVal = $('#testTitle').val();`

Comment: i updated my post to use `this` throughout, im not sure. i dont see the rest of ur code ^_^

Comment: @chromedude your `testTitleVal` is called before the blur ever happens. you need to use some closure and use `this` inside the blur to get the real value

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the variable testTitleVal somewhere else?

Try replacing that line with

```
if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` will always return true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `testTitleVal` is, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$('#testTitle').blur(
    function() {
        if (this.value.length === 0) {
            this.value = 'Title';
        }
    }
);
```

You may also want to look at the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute.